# Tableau: Unable to upload Data Source using REST. [NodeJS]

Tags: node.js, tableau-api, rest, tableau-desktop

I am trying to upload a data source to my tableau site using the following code:

```js
const request = require('request')
const fs = require('fs')
 
const options = {
  url: 'https://prod-apnortheast-a.online.tableau.com/api/3.12/sites/578341b7-325c-4dda-be08-ff0b10c4b18c/datasources',
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8',
    boundary: 'boundary-string'
  },
  body: `--boundary-string
          Content-Disposition: name="request_payload"
          Content-Type: text/xml
          <tsRequest>
              <datasource name="datasource-name"
              description="datasource-description">
                  <connectionCredentials name="xxxx@abc.com"
              password="xxxxxx"/>
                  <project id="96ec15ee-eef1-41ac-beda-1f03d9209305" />
            </datasource>
          </tsRequest>
          --boundary-string
          Content-Disposition: name="tableau_datasource"; filename="datasource-file-name"
          Content-Type: application/octet-stream
          This is the content of data source file.
          Hello from Mayank
        --boundary-string--`
}
 
function callback (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
  console.log( body, response.headers, response.statusCode)
}
 
request.post(options, callback)
```

But instead of a successful upload, I get the following error:

Response Body:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><tsResponse xmlns="http://tableau.com/api" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://tableau.com/api http://tableau.com/api/ts-api-3.12.xsd"><error code="406000"><summary>Bad Request</summary><detail>Content type 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8' not supported</detail></error></tsResponse>
```

Response Headers:

```
{
  'content-type': 'application/xml;charset=UTF-8',
  date: 'Mon, 30 Aug 2021 08:17:57 GMT',
  p3p: 'CP="NON"',
  'referrer-policy': 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
  server: 'Tableau',
  'set-cookie': [
    'hid=pdanaa-hap01; domain=.prod-apnortheast-a.online.tableau.com; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None',
    'AWSELB=05DBF7950E7E74D8AC3E3765F2EF65B6BB96F639EDB7A6D781435ACF3E27CEC2643898FB33239EFFBCA90E45D6EE0951AC6ECA4251ACA4E386D74627D58239403899B395F5F04C31144F69D44D5789C3FA7D6D9DC6;PATH=/;DOMAIN=.prod-apnortheast-a.online.tableau.com;SECURE;HTTPONLY;SAMESITE=None'
  ],
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
  tableau_error_code: '0xE3C7443A',
  tableau_error_source: 'NeedsClassification',
  tableau_service_name: 'vizportal',
  tableau_status_code: '2',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-tableau': 'Tableau Server',
  'x-ua-compatible': 'IE=Edge',
  'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
  'content-length': '365',
  connection: 'Close'
}
```

Response Status Code: 406

References:

1. https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_publishing.htm#publish_data_source
2. https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to Tableau's documentation [here](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_publish.htm)

> The Content-Type header for the request must be set to multipart/mixed; boundary=boundary-string.

Although I'm using PHP, I had this exact same error as you while trying to publish flows using the API. Changing to "multipart/mixed" in the Content-Type fixed it for me (wasn't the end of my problems though). So maybe changing your code to

```
...
headers: {
  Authorization: 'Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary=boundary-string'
},
...
```

could do the trick.

Please notice the content type change and that boundary is not a header by itself like you did.

Just note, your example code as it is might still generate 400 errors since that's not a valid data source file. Since I run Tableau Server I had to do a lot of troubleshooting by tailing the logs at the server and try to figure what was wrong.